# Angularjs ng-repeat not always firing on $last

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a ng-repeat with a filter, limitTo and directive.  The filter is from an input field and the list filters fine.  I am trying to track $last in a repeat-finish directive, this works fine most of the time, but there are certain strings when entered into the input field where the directive does not fire on $last.

I have included a fiddle here 
https://jsfiddle.net/1bzg1p7t/19/

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in vm.items | inputFilter:vm.inputSearch |limitTo: vm.limit" repeat-finish>{{item.showroomName}}</li>
</ul>
```

Problem String: 'yoo'

If you enter the string above in the input field you will see the alert does not fire 'finished' after the 'yo' but when you delete the 'o's it will fire.

Any help on why the $last does not fire would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: baskin please see my answer below

Comment: Thanks, so how do i consistently detect $last, i need to know when the filter ends.

Comment: Why do you need to know when the filter ends?

Comment: I want to stop the css loading spinner for slow filtering on mobile, there are 2000+ items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The link function is responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM. It is executed after the template has been cloned. This is where most of the directive logic will be put.

The [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-link-) function only gets executed after the template has been cloned(added to the dom) - the template here being your `<li>` item.

When you type "yo" the filter function filters out the items that does not match, and leaves the items that match in the list. As soon as you type the last "o" the remainder items are removed and you are left with only "YND Group LLC, DBA Seeka and Yoolie's".

As the "YND Group LLC, DBA Seeka and Yoolie's" item was already in the list(and in the DOM) when you typed "yo" the link function did not fire a second time when you typed the last "o"

I have forked your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xwtewqy/3/) and added a counter to each item when the link function fires. When you type "yoo" you will see the "Link Function Executed" value will be 1 as it only fired once.

updated dirctive:

```
.directive('repeatFinish', function($timeout){
        return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      if(scope.item.linkFunctionExecuted){
         scope.item.linkFunctionExecuted++;
      }else{
       scope.item.linkFunctionExecuted = 1;
      }

        if (scope.$last === true) {
          $timeout(function () {
            //console.log('--------------------------------------end');
          });
        }
      }
    };
});
```

updated HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app">


<div ng-controller="Main as vm">
  <input type="text" ng-model="vm.inputSearch">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in vm.items | inputFilter:vm.inputSearch |limitTo: vm.limit" repeat-finish>{{item.showroomName}} Link Function Executed{{item.linkFunctionExecuted}} times</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Not related to the question, just a tip: You can use the [placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) attribute  as a default value for the input then you don`t have to check for the value of "search"

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the timeout is being fired before the repeat has finished rendering - I have updated your fiddle to watch the value of `$last` and it appears to be working as expected

https://jsfiddle.net/1bzg1p7t/22/